# gdal_calc equation results in error: divide by zero

Tags: python, error, ndvi, gdal-calc

iIt is quite obvious to me that the rasterset A, B within the NDVI equation, --calc='"((A-B)/(A+B))"' with cell_value=0 will lead to the above error (division by zero). How can I avoid the error?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 --calc='"numpy.divide(A,B,out=np.zeros_like(A), where=(B*A)!=0)"'
```

will output 0 where either A or B is zero.

Comment: based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26248654/how-to-return-0-with-divide-by-zero/37977222#37977222

Answer (score 0):

You can not avoid the error but you can handle the error.  If you post your code you might get a more specific answer.  In any case have a look at Python error handling and more specifically how to handle zero division errors.
Something like this:

```
try:
    your code here
except ZeroDivisionError:
    pass
```

Check out these links.
[Error handling](http://zetcode.com/lang/python/exceptions/)
[From Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)
[From stack exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13646347/python-divide-by-zero-error).

Comment: Thanks a lot! it worked

Comment: @Andreas https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers